# C# add spaces between buttons in a loop

Tags: c#

I'm adding buttons to a panel in a loop from AppSettings keys, but why it isn't adding a little spaces between them?

```
foreach (var key in System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings)
            {
                x = 4;
                y = panel1.Controls.Count * 30;
                Button button = new Button();
                button.Text = key.ToString();
                button.Visible = true;
                button.Location = new Point(x+3, y+10);
                button.Height = 45;
                button.Width = 308;
                button.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
                button.Show();

                panel1.Controls.Add(button);
            }
```

How it is look now:

[image]

And what I want:

[image]

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Don't use a `Panel` in the first place. Use a `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel`. That way, you don't have to care about the `Location` at all as the parent will handle the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at how the following values change for the three iterations of your loop:

| panel1.Controls.Count | y | button.Location.y (y + 10) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 10 |
| 1 | 30 | 40 |
| 2 | 60 | 70 |

Since the height of each button is `45`, but you're only increasing `y` by `30`, the buttons are overlapping by `15`.

To get rid of the overlap and add the space in between buttons that you want, you need to increase the value of `y` by (button height + padding amount) on each loop iteration. For example, with a button height of `45` and desired padding of `10`, you'd want to increment by `55`:

```
y = panel1.Controls.Count * 55;
```

You could also achieve the same effect by decreasing the height of the button:

```
button.Height = 25;
```

As mentioned by @user18387401 in a comment, you could also explore using other controls that will handle this sort of layout for you so that you don't have to perform these calculations manually.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't even a programming problem but a basic maths and reading problem. The `Height` of each `Button` is 45 pixels:

```cs
button.Height = 45;
```

while the `Top` of each `Button` will be a 10 plus some multiple of 30:

```cs
y = panel1.Controls.Count * 30;
// ...
button.Location = new Point(x+3, y+10);
```

What's wrong with this picture? You only have to consider the first two `Buttons` to see the obvious issue, but you can go further if you want. The `Bottom` of the first `Button` will be 45 while the top of the second will be 1x30+10=40. Not a great start. The `Bottom` of the second `Button` will be 40+45=95 and the `Top` of the third `Button` will be 2x30+10=70. Do I need to go on?

Answer (score 0):

```
y = panel1.Controls.Count * 30;
```

Consider count to be 1;

```
y = 1
```

now `y+10` is 11, instead, you want a number around 50 (45 for button height and 5 for gaps)

Answer (score 0):

the properties seem familiar, so I will assume this is WPF.

So yeah, like others said, your math is a bit off.

However, you should not do that at all. You should use `ListView` or `ItemsControl` and bind the keys collection as `ItemsSource`.

You can google for tutorials on that, here is one: https://wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/

Following that will allow you to have a button for each key in your app settings. If you want each button to do a thing with the key, in your `ItemTemplate` bind to the same command, and bind the key as `CommandParameter`- that sentence should give you enough keywords to google from here.

Yes, you can fix your math and be done, or do it "properly" (I will probably get some hate for that :) ). This is not how you create UIs in WPF (or Winforms for that matter). The fact that you CAN does not mean that you SHOULD.

Good luck!